# How can I run the latest version of Chrome on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, development, version

In a bug post I sent to the Chrome developers, a developer sent me the message:

> We don't see this difference in the
>   new builds of Chrome. Checked in
>   6.0.437.2 dev. Can you check and confirm again?

I'm wondering how can I run the latest (development) version of Chrome for Mac OS X?

Ideally I don't want to build the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to subscribe to the Dev channel.  The instructions for doing this are [here](http://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel).